# C++ 11 with Raspberry Pi performances

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, raspberry-pi

I have some questions for you, I will have to do a program under a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian OS.
I'll do it with C++11 but I have to justify that choice.

Is it a really gain of performances ? I can't find something like "Performances differences C++ and C++11" on Google... I'm searching for some good informations but... =/

I will have to do like 2 or 3 threads in it, I know that C++11 has a new system for this with std::thread but, why is it really better than the previous threading system ?

Thanks guys =( I really need help for it =/

Comment: There really aren't any performance differences between *any* C++ version, only what comes with the compilers being better at optimization.

Comment: As for `std::thread` compared to other threading (Boost or POSIX), the difference between the standard threads and Boost is not much, but between standard and POSIX there is a lot, most of all that the standard threads can handle lambdas and `std::bind`/`std::function` objects.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers !

So for performances: No really gain but compilers will be better at code optimization. Oki

For the thread I think I have understand yes, and I read that you can now have variables in a thread and only for it if you want, if you wanna modify it in thread "a" it will not be changed in thread "b". That's great =P

Comment: There are some C++11 features that help compiler produce more optimized code, namely `constexpr` and `nothrow`.

Comment: Move semantics also. Moving an object is often more efficient than copying it.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can come up with for performance if you use any of the following new features.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Core_language_runtime_performance_enhancements

To be explicit about it, I do not see any significant performance gain you could obtain in here other than the usual differences that may occur among the compilers. However, there should be no big difference among the major ones.